# Searchable integer managed property - ows_ListItemId

Tags: search, search-results, enterprise-search, managed-property

In SharePoint 2013 on-prem I have managed property of type Integer that is storing the ows_ListItemId crawled property.

Managed property has Searchable, Retrievable and Queryable check. Crawled property has "Include in full-text index" checked.

However I can't search for Id directly from search box using just the id number. It doesn't show anything. Only the "ManagedProperty:Value" search box query is working.

Is there a way to enter only the id number in search box and get results?

EDIT 1:
I've forced the re-index on site and on list (source of items) . Still not working.